# How do I print my Java object without getting “something@677327b6” Without Overriding?

Tags: java, overriding, tostring, hashcode

I have this method defined:

```
    @Override
    public String toString(String line)
    {
        String[] categories = line.split("; ");
        String[] info;

        // Get the suspect's information
        info = categories[0].split(", ");
        suspect = new Person(info[0].charAt(0), Integer.parseInt(info[1]), Double.parseDouble(info[2]));
        String str = "";
        if (info[0].charAt(0) == 'M')
            str += "Male, ";
        else if (info[0].charAt(0) == 'F')
            str += "Female, ";
        else
            str += "unknown, ";
        str += Integer.parseInt(info[1]) + "'s, ";
        str += Double.parseDouble(info[2]) +"m";
        System.out.println(str);
        return str;
    }
}
```

When I was running this through the command line before the addition of `@Override` I was getting an output similar to this: `Detective@677327b6` in terminal.

I understand that this is the hashcode that is being output. 
However, I need it to print the str as I have defined in the toString() method.

The problem is that The method toString(String) of type Detective must override or implement a supertype method, my only solution is to remove the `@Override` annotation.

So what other way can I access the correct value as opposed to overriding them?

Comment: if you use eclipse you can go to menu source->generate toString. with that you get a void method, which prints all data

Answer (score 1):

This is not the usual `toString` method declared in the Object class is it?

```
@Override
public String toString(String line)
```

The one on object does not take any arguments...

```
@Override
public String toString() { ... }
```

Where does `line` come from?

If you stored `line` in the (`Detective`?) class itself, then you could use the correct `toString` signature.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes I stored it in the detective class. I removed the arguments, and intialized line to null. Now I get these errors `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Detective.toString(Detective.java:82)
 at java.lang.String.valueOf(String.java:2994)
 at java.lang.StringBuilder.append(StringBuilder.java:131)`

Comment: @sd2000e Not sure what line 82 is, but is `line` set to `null` by any chance? Use a debugger and step through your `toStirng` code

Comment: My apologies. I made a mistake in my comment. I initialized line to null within the toString.

Comment: The value after the @ **is** the hash code. See [API docs of `Object.toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#toString--). The fact that `Object.hashCode()` returns the address, is a separate thing.

Comment: @Jesper I always thought it was a memory address, you are correct, I'll change my answer... (you learn something new every day...) Thanks